# Return type casting with generics and dynamic class type

Tags: java, class, generics, casting

I'm trying to avoid explicitly casting a return from a method.

What I have works well if I specify the class statically at compile-time, but I'd prefer to get the class from an enum type, during runtime.

```
public enum Type {

    SOME_TYPE(Clazz.class),
    ;

    private Type(Class<?> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    private final Class<?> clazz;

    public Class<?> getClazz() {
        return this.clazz;
    }
}

public class Foo {

    private Foo() {}

    public static <T> T doSomething(Class<T> clazz, String input) {
        // ...
        final Object obj = someProcess(input);

        return clazz.cast(obj);
    }
}

public class Bar {

    public void stuff() {

        // does not work without explicit casting to SomeClass
        // compiler error
        Clazz sc = Foo.doSomething(Type.SOME_TYPE.getClazz(), someInputData);

        // this does work, without an explicit cast
        Clazz sc2 = Foo.doSomething(Clazz.class, someInputData);
    }
}
```

I have a feeling this is not possible to do dynamically, because the compiler cannot be sure what class will be returned from the `getClazz()` method.

How can I make this work?

Comment: generics only exist at compile time for extended compile-time type safety.

Comment: For what you are trying to achieve, it seems like you'll need that explicit cast

Comment: @ControlAltDel I'll just specify the class explicitly if I must (like the `sc2` option), it's just harder to use that way. I was afraid that might be it...

Comment: I've updated the example to return `sc` and `sc2` of type `Clazz`, which it should have been all along. Typed my example too quickly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generics allow you to omit a cast *if* the compiler can prove that value will be of a compatible type for the operation.

In your working `sc2` example, the compiler can see that you're passing the `Class` object for the `Class` class.  `doSomething` promises to return an object whose type matches the type token (and the compiler will validate that as well), so it is provable that `doSomething` in this case will return a `Class` instance; no cast needed.

But by the nature of selecting the `Class` instance dynamically, it becomes impossible for the compiler to prove that the type will be compatible for this assignment.  As far as the compiler can tell, you might load code that would change which `Class` is being supplied as the type token, and that would change what's returned.  Since there is a potential for an incompatible assignment, which would have to throw an exception, the rules of Java require an explicit cast.

There's logically no way to do exactly what you're asking, essentially by design.

It's hard to come up with alternatives without knowing more about what you're trying to accomplish, because any substitute approach will have limitations and I don't know which ones are acceptable.  Of course the easiest case would be if there is (or can be) a useful common base class or interface for all the things you might return; but I assume if that were so you wouldn't be looking at this kind of design.

Comment: `Clazz` is a complex type that does share a common base class with other possible class type inputs, however to access higher level methods the user would still need to cast unfortunately. `Foo` is a converter of sorts, that takes XML data and outputs a POJO. The POJO class depends on what type of XML document is being converted, hence the need to specify the class as an input.

Comment: Hm... I think I misread a `Clazz` as `Class` in your code, so may have a confused line or two in the answer.  I'll take another look and see if I can clean it up a bit, but the key takeaway I believe is the same

Answer (score 2):

> I'm trying to avoid explicitly casting a return from a method.

Currently, the compiler cannot infer anything from

```
Type.SOME_TYPE.getClazz()
```

because this expression refers to a `Class` typed with a wildcard :

```
private final Class<?> clazz;

public Class<?> getClazz() {
    return this.clazz;
}
```

How the compiler could guess that it needs to cast it to `SomeClass` ?

The `Class` defined in the enum is definitively too generics.
I don't think that this design suits to your need.
If you want to avoid any cast, replace

```
Type.SOME_TYPE.getClazz()
```

by something that explicits the class you want to the method return :

```
SomeClass.class
```

such as

```
SomeClass sc =  Foo.doSomething(SomeClass.class, someInputData);
```

Comment: It doesn't change your answer really, but see my update above. I mistakenly typed `SomeClass` when it should have been `Clazz`... anyway, it is client code that will be using `Foo.doSomething()`, and I was attempting to make it easier to input a supported class type.

Comment: As you guessed it changes nothing as `getClazz()` returns  `Class<?>`. To make it working `getClazz()` should return `Clazz` but in this case no value to define it in a field of the enum values as all cast will be done to `Clazz`. To make things simple for the clients, I advise to not use an enum for this requirement and favor classes passing as parameter.